# Setting QSurfaceFormat has no effect

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am currently having issues with getting a debug context with Qt 5.8 on Windows.

I am using Qt 5.8 to write a small OpenGL application, using a viewer class declared like this

```
class GLViewer3DModel : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    //...
};
```

My `main.cpp`file uses this code, before QApplication is initialized:

```
 QSurfaceFormat format;     
 format.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext);
 format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
 QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

In the 3D viewer's constructor, the `QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext` option seems to be properly set. However, if I test this again within my `initializeGL` override, the following code

```
void GLViewer3DModel::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    QSurfaceFormat fmt = format();
    bool hasDebug = fmt.testOption(QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext);    
    std::cout << "STILL DEBUG? " << hasDebug << std::endl;
}
```

prints "STILL DEBUG? 0", so for some reason the format has changed.
Can I do anything to make the debug context work? I would love to use `QOpenGLDebugLogger` to see where something might go wrong.

FWIW, the `GL_KHR_debug` extension is supported on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a OpenGL version greater then 4.1 as I think that's when the debug was made core. The default constructed QSurfaceFormat requests GL 2.0 which doesn't support debug. See what you get then.

Also try initialising the logger and see what it spits back at you

Comment: P.S.: I still can't get a debug context - but that seems to be related to the fact that they use ANGLE on Windows, or on my GPU / Driver... at least, I cannot get a 4.0 (or higher) OpenGL context :-/
This is especially sad since `GL_KHR_debug` *is* supported on my system